# Go - imported and not used but necessary

Tags: go

I try to import a go package but I get the following error::

```
.\data.go:10:2: "github.com/username/test/my-project/model" imported and not used
.\data.go:38:13: undefined: DataModel
```

these are my go files:

**main.go**

```
package main

func main() {consumeApi()}
```

**data.go**

```
package main

import(
    "github.com/username/test/my-project/model"
)

func consumeApi() {
    ...
    var result DataModel
    if err := json.Unmarshal(body, &result); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Can not unmarshal JSON")
    }
    ...
}
```

```
model.go
```

```
package model

type DataModel struct {
...
}
```

**go.mod**

```
module github.com/username/test/my-project

go 1.21.0
```

Can anyone help me solve it?

Comment: is that project actually on github? besides, if you import a package 'model', then a type from that package would be declared e.g. like `var result model.DataModel`

Comment: Please, start with reading at least some basic material. The problem you're facing [is covered](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/getting-started#call) in the _first_ tutorial which follows the installation guide, [here](https://go.dev/doc/). [The Go Tour](https://go.dev/tour/) is also a must.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
var result DataModel
```

to

```
var result model.DataModel
```